# Matrix representation of orthogonal groups.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

**Problem:**

> Find the matrix representation of $\text{O}(1,\mathbb R)$.

Where $\text{O}(1,\mathbb R)$ is the orthogonal group. 
 **Attempt:** I've tried to compute it normally using the standard linear algebra matrix representation but I'm getting nowhere. Another question is there a general method for computing the matrix representation of orthogonal groups $\text{O}(n,\mathbb R)$? 
 
 Any help and hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: But you only need the orthogonal transformations of the real line, isn't that so?  What are these?

Comment: $2 \times 2$ matrix of with $\cos$ and $\sin$ entries?